# #define ... method call. Why?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I have come across some of this sort of thing in a codebase I need to get across:

```
#define TimeStamp [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]) ]
```

Why would someone do this, as opposed to creating a method in the implementation? Seems such an odd thing to do, but there must be some benefit to it.

Comment: No there isn't much benefit, don't use macro, use inline function.

Comment: It's getting the Unix epoch timestamp.  I suspect that since its a Unix value there's a tendency to believe it should be a macro.  Different strokes for different folks.

Answer (score 1):

As per [High Order Blog](http://weblog.highorderbit.com/post/11656225202/appropriate-use-of-c-macros-for-objective-c):-

In some scenarios macros provide necessary functionality not available through other means. One example is when you do need to actually have the context of the current code location at hand when the code executes.

For example, I have a simple macro I sometimes use when debugging Objective-C to log when certain methods are called. This can be done like so:

```
NSLog(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

This can’t be moved into an Objective-C method because it will always log the name of that method. (Obviously it can’t be moved into a C method, as there is no self and no _cmd variables available.) Creating a macro for this is straightforward, however:

```
#define LOG_SELECTOR()  NSLog(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it done in C a lot, it just make the code inline rather than in separate function

It removes the overhead of calling a function, when the function is just a line long.It forces it to be inline

Pretty much any compiler would make that small a function in-line anyway so there isn't a really good reason to do this. More of a stylistic choice. It is also very error-prone

Comment: It doesn't really remove much overhead (compiler/linker can remove it anyway). Use macro is for something that inline function can be done is always bad.

Comment: You can't inline Objective-C methods, so unless you turned it into an actual function, it won't be inlined and thus will incur a message send all the time. Such a cost is at an all time low, so there's really no excuse to use `#define` like this anymore.